# Как синхронно задать класс порядковым элементам при наведении?

Tags: javascript, css

Есть симмитричных два блока, внутри них - много span, каждый - с новой строки. Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на любой из span задавался класс hovered ему и симметричному ему span?

```css
.col {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
.hovered {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-part col">
  <span>Слово 1</span>
  <span>Слово 2</span>
  <span>Слово 3</span>
  <span>Слово 4</span>
  <span>Слово 5</span>
  <span>Слово 6</span>
</div>
<div class="right-part col">
  <span>Слово 1</span>
  <span>Слово 2</span>
  <span>Слово 3</span>
  <span>Слово 4</span>
  <span>Слово 5</span>
  <span>Слово 6</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Зазор между блоками сделан намеренно или в реальном коде его нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но это если равное кол-во элементов.
По хорошему требуется оптимизация - сопоставление блока 1 с блоком 2.
Ниже очень простой вариант с поиском текущего индекса элемента.

```js
const divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('div')]

for (const div of divs) {
  div.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseover)
}

const storage = []

function resetClass() {
  for (const span of storage.splice(0)) {
    span.classList.remove('hovered')
  }
}

function addClass(spans) {
  resetClass()
  for (const span of spans) {
    span.classList.add('hovered')
    storage.push(span)
  }
}

function mouseover(e) {
  const target = e.target
  if (target.tagName !== 'SPAN' || storage.includes(target)) {
    return
  }
  const div1 = e.currentTarget
  const div2 = divs.find((d) => d !== div1)
  const index = [...div1.children].findIndex((s) => s === target)
  const target2 = div2.children[index]
  addClass([target, target2])
}
```

```css
.col {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: block;
}

.hovered {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-part col">
  <span>Слово 1</span>
  <span>Слово 2</span>
  <span>Слово 3</span>
  <span>Слово 4</span>
  <span>Слово 5</span>
  <span>Слово 6</span>
</div>
<div class="right-part col">
  <span>Слово 1</span>
  <span>Слово 2</span>
  <span>Слово 3</span>
  <span>Слово 4</span>
  <span>Слово 5</span>
  <span>Слово 6</span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

- Сопоставляем все родственные элементы. Теперь при mouseover не надо искать индексы.
- MutationObserver на случай изменения блоков.

```js
const containers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.col')]

class SpanWeakMap extends WeakMap {
  addItems (...items) {
    items.forEach((e) => this.set(e, items))
  }
  classListAdd (e, ...className) {
    this.get(e)?.forEach((item) => item.classList.add(...className))
  }
  classListRemove (e, ...className) {
    this.get(e)?.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove(...className))
  }
}

const spanMap = new SpanWeakMap(/* span:[left.span, right.span, ...], ... */)

// Сопоставление - каждый элемент будет ссылаться на все родственные
function collect () {
  const cs = containers.map((col) => [...col.querySelectorAll('span')])
  cs[0].forEach((_, i) =>
    spanMap.addItems(...cs.map((_, ic) => cs[ic][i])))
}
collect()

// Наблюдаем за обновлением коллекций - добавление/удаление элементов(не обязательо если <div class=".col"> не меняется
const observe = (() => {
  let tid = null
  const update = () => {
    clearTimeout(tid)
    tid = setTimeout(collect, 100)
  }
  return (con) => new MutationObserver(update).observe(con, { childList: true })
})()

// Навешиваем обработчики на все ".col"
containers.forEach((con) => {
  observe(con)
  // Можно не проверять на тег SPAN, наш SpanWeakMap сам все проверит
  con.addEventListener('mouseover', ({ target }) => spanMap.classListAdd(target, 'hovered', 'color-white'))
  con.addEventListener('mouseout', ({ target }) => spanMap.classListRemove(target, 'hovered', 'color-white'))
})


// +++ Только для эксперимента обновления коллекций +++
// Пробуем добавить/удалить элементы каждые 2 сек
void (() => {
  const count = 2
  const add = () => {
    const last = containers[0].querySelector('span:nth-last-child(-n+1)')
    const newElements = (num) => Array(count).fill(null).map(() => {
      const e = last.cloneNode(true)
      e.classList.remove('hovered', 'color-white')
      e.textContent = last.textContent.replace(/\d/, num++)
      return e
    })
    const num = Number.parseInt(last.textContent.match(/\d/)[0]) + 1
    containers.forEach((col) => col.append(...newElements(num)))
  }
  const remove = () => {
    const lastItems = [...containers[0].querySelectorAll(`span:nth-last-child(-n+${count})`)]
    lastItems.forEach((item) => spanMap.get(item)?.forEach((e) => e.remove()))
  }
  let invert = false
  setInterval(() => ((invert = !invert) ? add() : remove()), 2000)
})()
```

```css
.col {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

span {
  display: block;
}

.hovered {
  background: red;
}

.color-white {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-part col">
  <span>Слово 1</span>
  <span>Слово 2</span>
  <span>Слово 3</span>
  <span>Слово 4</span>
</div>
<div class="right-part col">
  <span>Слово 1</span>
  <span>Слово 2</span>
  <span>Слово 3</span>
  <span>Слово 4</span>
</div>
<div class="some-part col">
  <span>Слово 1</span>
  <span>Слово 2</span>
  <span>Слово 3</span>
  <span>Слово 4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а как сделать, чтобы при снятии hover'a со span  убирались классы?

Comment: @Alex Тогда добавим mouseout. Обновил и добавил SpanWeakMap для оптимизации + не зависит от кол-ва блоков.

Comment: Его что-то штормит при выполнении. Появляется Слово 5, Слово 6

Comment: @Alex Так это не "штормит" :), я же подписал, в самом последнем блоке кода - это эксперимент обновления данных.

Comment: Спасибо за отличный скрипт, многому на нему научился. Подскажите, а есть способ сделать так, чтобы в случае, если внутри span имеется другой тег, родительский span всё-равно выделялся?

Comment: @Alex Добавить дополнительную функцию, [что-то вроде такого](https://jsfiddle.net/x2n4u016/), с поиском родительского элемента строки.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так. Наверно можно как-то элегантнее, но мне пора пиво пить идти :).

```js
const leftCollection = document.querySelectorAll('.left-part > span');
const rightCollection = document.querySelectorAll('.right-part > span');

const toggleClass = (i) => {
  leftCollection[i].classList.toggle('hovered');
  rightCollection[i].classList.toggle('hovered');
};

leftCollection.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    toggleClass(i);
  });
  el.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    toggleClass(i);
  });
});

rightCollection.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    toggleClass(i);
  });
  el.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    toggleClass(i);
  });
});
```

```css
.col {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
.hovered {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-part col">
  <span>Слово 1</span>
  <span>Слово 2</span>
  <span>Слово 3</span>
  <span>Слово 4</span>
  <span>Слово 5</span>
  <span>Слово 6</span>
</div>
<div class="right-part col">
  <span>Слово 1</span>
  <span>Слово 2</span>
  <span>Слово 3</span>
  <span>Слово 4</span>
  <span>Слово 5</span>
  <span>Слово 6</span>
</div>
```

Comment: да, можно еще короче - навешивание ивентов в отдельную функцию вынести )

Comment: а разве нельзя event listener вешать просто на div и уже по event.target в коде js применять изменение?

Comment: Pavel Nazarian: Да, точняк

Comment: xmikex: Не уверен, что мы можем как-то легко и просто получить индекс, а тут вся "красота" решения на этом строится. Надо подумать об этом. Понятно что можно, но код по итогу вырастет как мне кажется.

Answer (score 2):

Обработать в любом случае нужно 2 блока, левый и правый. Вот мое решение по js  коду.

```js
const blocksLeft = document.querySelectorAll('.left-part span');
const blocksRight = document.querySelectorAll('.right-part span');

const getObjectUantity = (...length) => {
  const [blocksLeftLength, blocksRightLength] = length;
  const min = blocksLeftLength;
  const max = blocksRightLength;
  const maxQuantity = max >= min ? max : min;
  const minQuantity = max >= min ? min : max;
  const uantity = maxQuantity - minQuantity;

  return {
    maxQuantity,
    minQuantity,
    uantity,
  };
};

const objUantity = getObjectUantity(blocksLeft.length, blocksRight.length);

const addClassHovered = (settings = {}) => {
  settings = {
    blocks: '',
    index: 0,
    classCss: 'hovered',
    ...settings,
  };

  const { blocks, index, classCss } = settings;

  if (objUantity.uantity !== 0) {
    return 'hovered не может быть добавлен в вашем случае элементы не равны.';
  }

  if (objUantity.uantity === 0) {
    blocks[index].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      blocksLeft[index].classList.add(classCss);
      blocksRight[index].classList.add(classCss);
    });

    blocks[index].addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
      blocksLeft[index].classList.remove(classCss);
      blocksRight[index].classList.remove(classCss);
    });
  }
};

for (let i = 0; i < objUantity.maxQuantity; i++) {
  const index = i;
  addClassHovered({ blocks: blocksLeft, index });
  addClassHovered({ blocks: blocksRight, index });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучше немного поменять разметку и использовать css:

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0 8px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

span {
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

span:hover, span:hover + span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <span>Слово 1</span>
  <span>Слово 1</span>
  <span>Слово 2</span>
  <span>Слово 2</span>
  <span>Слово 3</span>
  <span>Слово 3</span>
  <span>Слово 4</span>
  <span>Слово 4</span>
  <span>Слово 5</span>
  <span>Слово 5</span>
  <span>Слово 6</span>
  <span>Слово 6</span>
</section>
```

Comment: почти *(нужно ещё 10 символов...)*

Comment: @Igor, что почти? И я уже исхитрился с сохранением разметки)

Comment: Я ошибся, мне казалось, что ему нужна реализация на javaScript.

Comment: @WalkMess, ну у вопроса оба тега. Может он не знал, что можно без js? Варианты есть, выберет подходящий.

Answer (score 2):

Даже не меняя разметку можно обойтись только css. Хотя и не факт, что так лучше.

Если пустота между колонками не нужна, можно сделать так:

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
}

section::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}

span:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1.25em;
  z-index: -1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left-part col">
    <span>Слово 1</span>
    <span>Слово 2</span>
    <span>Слово 3</span>
    <span>Слово 4</span>
    <span>Слово 5</span>
    <span>Слово 6</span>
  </div><div class="right-part col">
    <span>Слово 1</span>
    <span>Слово 2</span>
    <span>Слово 3</span>
    <span>Слово 4</span>
    <span>Слово 5</span>
    <span>Слово 6</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

А если всё-таки нужна, то так:

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(90% + 8px);
  --colwidth: calc(50% - 4px);
}

.col {
  width: var(--colwidth);
  display: inline-block;
}

.col::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: inherit;
  z-index: -2;
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

.left-part {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}

span:hover::before, span:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1.25em;
  width: var(--colwidth);
  z-index: -1;
  background: red;
}

span:hover::before {
  left: 0;
}

span:hover::after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left-part col">
    <span>Слово 1</span>
    <span>Слово 2</span>
    <span>Слово 3</span>
    <span>Слово 4</span>
    <span>Слово 5</span>
    <span>Слово 6</span>
  </div><div class="right-part col">
    <span>Слово 1</span>
    <span>Слово 2</span>
    <span>Слово 3</span>
    <span>Слово 4</span>
    <span>Слово 5</span>
    <span>Слово 6</span>
  </div>
</section>
```